# Use a public static method to initialize another object's field

Tags: java

I have a class as follows:

```
public class MyClass {
   ...
   String lang = Config.getLang();
   ...
}
```

`Config.getLang()` is a public static method in class named `Config`. My question is: Does this initialization have any implication or problem?

```
String lang = Config.getLang();
```

Eclipse does not report any compilation problem.

Comment: It's very common pattern used and called factory method.

Comment: @texasbruce That's not what I would call a "factory method"..

Comment: The 'limitations' of the inline field assignment are hinted at in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

Comment: Let's flip this around:  why would you think that this would be a problem?

Comment: Makoto, user2864740's link explains the implication I want to know.

Comment: @user2864740 why do you think ?why it can not be called factory method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As posted and described (and in general) it's perfectly valid to initialize a field by calling a static method (even if that method is in another class).